# Empty array when dd($request->all()) upload file via ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

first of all i try to do the file uploading via ajax , when i try `dd($request->all())`in my controller , it give result `empty array`

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){
   
    dd($request->all());

}
```

My blade view with ajax

```
<label for="inputfile">
  <a  title="Click here to upload record "><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
</label>
    <input id="inputfile" name="inputfile" type="file" />



 <script>

 $('#inputfile').on('change',function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault(); 
   var postData=new FormData();
   postData.append('file',this.files[0]);
    
      $.ajax({
            url:'{{url('reporting/uploadFile')}}',
            headers:{'X-CSRF-Token':$('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')},
            type:"get",
            contentType:false,
            data:postData,
            processData:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function( data ) {
               console.log(data)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }    });    }); 
    </script>
```

My laravel version is 5.8 . The flow is when the user upload attachment, it will directly store to  file storage without clicking button submit . But when i try to retrieve $request->all() its return empty array which is i can't continue further step. Sorry if my explaination not clear .

Comment: is `dd($request->file('file'))` also empty? Sometimes it isn't included in `all`. Also check the console for any browser JS errors

Comment: @apokryfos no error in my console . dd($request->file('file')) also null

Comment: Why are you using the method `get` for form submission? You should use `post` instead, or in the case of `patch` you need to append the formData `_method: post` for getting files in laravel side

Comment: Set headers of your ajax request to: `'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes ok laravel can be a real pain sometimes especially when it comes to file uploads.

You can try this article for laravel 5.8 give it a try and let me know if it works.

https://www.w3adda.com/blog/laravel-5-8-jquery-ajax-form-submit

I think the main difference with this article is the way it sets the data in the ajax call. However you might need to check the whole article over and compare it to your code.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "{{ url('jquery-ajax-form-submit')}}",
  method: 'post',
  data: $('#contact_us').serialize(),
```

Comment: i already tried based on this blog but still not working , guess i just do normal way instead of ajax . thanks for your help mate :))

Comment: sure thats ok. I was just checking one of my older projects and found this. "$uploadedFile = $request->file('post_video_upload');" i think the request also has a file function to retrieve files you might be able to use. So rather than using $request->get('key'); try using $request->file('key');

Comment: My last comment above this one is also written in the laravel documentation, i just checked for laravel 5.8 and 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are using the form multipart setting correctly.
This is usually the issue in most cases.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I already do this before still not working sir...

Answer (score 0):

```
 let files = $('#inputfile');
    let image = files[0].files;

let form_data = new FormData();
    if (image.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
            form_data.append('inputfile[]', image[i]);
    }


            $.ajax({
            url:'{{url('reporting/uploadFile')}}',
            headers:{'X-CSRF-Token':$('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content')},
            type:"get",
            contentType:false,
            data:form_data,
            processData:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function( data ) {
               console.log(data)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }    
            });    
          });
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set "Content-Type" in header.
You also have pass type get, for file upload must require post.
have you console.log(this.files[0]);

```
<script>

 $('#inputfile').on('change',function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault(); 
   console.log(this.files[0]);
   var postData=new FormData();
   postData.append('file',this.files[0]);
    
      $.ajax({
            url:'{{url('reporting/uploadFile')}}',
            headers:{
               'X-CSRF-Token':$('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr('content'),
               'Content-Type': undefined 
            },
            type:"POST",
            data:postData,
            success: function( data ) {
               console.log(data)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }    });    }); 
    </script>
```